# pusher notification not working as listed in the example

Tags: javascript, python, pusher

I am running the pusher demo code that was provided upon user registration and having issues and looking for help.

The client is JS and Server code is Python in App Engine.

I find that the notifications are working fine when I launch a event from event creator.

However, when I use the sample python code and launch from app engine, I get 2 alert message boxes:

> Box1: The page at localhost:8080 says [object Object]
>
> Box2: The page at pusher.com says [object Object]

**My python code:**

```
p = pusher.Pusher(app_id='45392', key='..', secret='..')
p['test_channel'].trigger('my_event',{'message': 'hello world'})
```

**My Javascript code:**

```
var pusher = new Pusher('...');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
alert(data);
```

Comment: Could you please let me know where you found the client code? And which docs you are referring to that are incorrect. Both bits of code do work but I'd expect the client code to do `alert( data.message );`. The quickstart guide is definitely correct: http://pusher.com/docs/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

The example is totaly correct actually you have to know that you are send object so you can excess your message as data.message rather then pass data in alert function.

```
var pusher = new Pusher('...');
var channel = pusher.subscribe('test_channel');
channel.bind('my_event', function(data) {
alert(data.message);
```